# Cypher Neo4j Count number of bidirectional Relationship between two nodes and avoid duplicate results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here is my query:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:Sent]->(m2:message)-[r:forward]->(m1:message)<-[Sent]-(b:Person)
   WITH a, b, COUNT(r) as count
   RETURN a,b,count
```

Here is the result sample:

```
  a             b            count
   name1         name2          2
   name2         name1          3
```

and I want to get the sum of forwarded messages between the 2 nodes in both direction, therefore I don't want to have duplicated results like on the previous example

For the previous example I want such kind of results:

```
 a             b            count
name1         name2          5
```

I tried many queries but couldn't find any solution or syntax to get this results.

Is there any way to get this kind of results? 
Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you'd get the total number of forwarded messages between every applicable pair of people:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:Sent]->(:message)-[r:forward]-(:message)<-[:Sent]-(b:Person)
WHERE ID(a) < ID(b)
RETURN a, b, COUNT(r) as count;
```

The `MATCH` clause specifies a non-directional pattern for the `forward` relationship, so that it matches relationships in both directions. The `WHERE` clause ensures that you only get one row of results for each pair of people. *Also, this query uses `[:Sent]` consistently, fixing a typo in your original query.*

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help.
it solved my problem but I needed to remove the directions from my path to get the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:Sent]->(m2:message)-[r:forward]->(m1:message)<-[:Sent]-(b:Person)
WITH COLLECT(a) as rows, count(r) as count
RETURN {a:properties(rows[0]), b:properties(rows[1]), count: count}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help.
Now, I got the results that I want but unfortunatly I still have duplicate results like

`code
 a             b            count
name1         name2          5
name2         name1         5
`

Comment: You are welcome! :) If this answer solved your problem remember to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for informs others that your issue is resolved and to help future viewers of your question.

Comment: I'm still struggling with the duplication problem, the LIMIT 1 will give just one result and skip all the other results for different nodes

Comment: name1,name2, count for me is same as name2,name1, count but I don't know how to express this with Cypher syntax

Comment: @Brenna Edited the answer. Try now! :)